# Migrating link for 36597 of type RelatedLink [SKIP] Unable to migrate link where Link of type System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools, tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

We need your help to migrate links to another organization. We are using the azure DevOps migration tool version 11.6.

We ran the full migration using this tool and it seems work-items are properly migrated but links are skipping to migrate.

Here the things which we need to migrate.

Attachments like an image
Related links with associated Parent and child relationship
and My template is (Source) IP CMMI and (Destination) Scrum.  I got the below error while I run the migration. please help me regarding it.

We raise the problem at https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/662

We got this error:
Migrating link for 36597 of type RelatedLink [SKIP] Unable to migrate link where Link of type System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse where wiSourceL=36597, wiSourceR=36591, wiTargetL=6222, wiTargetR=36591 as target WI has not been migrated GitRepositoryEnricher: Enriching 6222 To fix Git Repo Links

Configuration File :

```json
    {
    "ChangeSetMappingFile": null,
    "Source": {
    "ObjectType": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/Prashantshivhare01/",
    "Project": "TestMigration",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "PersonalAccessToken": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
    "AreaPath": "Area",
    "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
    },
    "Target": {
    "ObjectType": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/dest01",
    "Project": "Test Migration",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "PersonalAccessToken": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
    "AreaPath": "Area",
    "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
    },
    "FieldMaps": [
    {
    "ObjectType": "MultiValueConditionalMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceFieldsAndValues": {
    "Field1": "Value1",
    "Field2": "Value2"
    },
    "targetFieldsAndValues": {
    "Field1": "Value1",
    "Field2": "Value2"
    }
    },
    {
    "ObjectType": "FieldBlankMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "targetField": "TfsMigrationTool.ReflectedWorkItemId"
    },
    {
    "ObjectType": "FieldValueMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceField": "System.State",
    "targetField": "System.State",
    "defaultValue": "New",
    "valueMapping": {
    "Approved": "New",
    "New": "New",
    "Committed": "Active",
    "In Progress": "Active",
    "To Do": "New",
    "Done": "Closed",
    "Removed": "Removed"
    }
    },
    {
    "ObjectType": "FieldtoFieldMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceField": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority",
    "targetField": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank",
    "defaultValue": null
    },
    {
    "ObjectType": "FieldtoFieldMultiMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "SourceToTargetMappings": {
    "SourceField1": "TargetField1",
    "SourceField2": "TargetField2"
    }
    },
    {
    "ObjectType": "FieldtoTagMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceField": "System.State",
    "formatExpression": "ScrumState:{0}"
    },
    {
    "ObjectType": "FieldMergeMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceField1": "System.Description",
    "sourceField2": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria",
    "targetField": "System.Description",
    "formatExpression": "{0}
    
    
    Acceptance Criteria
    {1}",
    "doneMatch": "##DONE##"
    },
    {
    "ObjectType": "RegexFieldMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceField": "COMPANY.PRODUCT.Release",
    "targetField": "COMPANY.DEVISION.MinorReleaseVersion",
    "pattern": "PRODUCT \d{4}.(\d{1})",
    "replacement": "$1"
    },
    {
    "ObjectType": "FieldValuetoTagMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceField": "Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Blocked",
    "pattern": "Yes",
    "formatExpression": "{0}"
    },
    {
    "ObjectType": "TreeToTagMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "toSkip": 3,
    "timeTravel": 1
    }
    ],
    "GitRepoMapping": null,
    "LogLevel": "Information",
    "Processors": [
    {
    "ObjectType": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
    "ReplayRevisions": true,
    "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
    "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
    "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
    "BuildFieldTable": false,
    "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
    "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] = '' AND [System.WorkItemType] IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
    "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
    "Enabled": true,
    "LinkMigration": true,
    "AttachmentMigration": true,
    "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\temp\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\",
    "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
    "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
    "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
    "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
    "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": true,
    "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
    "CollapseRevisions": false,
    "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
    "GenerateMigrationComment": true,
    "NodeBasePaths": [
    "Product\Area\Path1",
    "Product\Area\Path2"
    ],
    "WorkItemIDs": null
    }
    ],
    "Version": "11.6",
    "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
    "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
    "sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName",
    "Bug" : "Bug",
    "Requirement" : "Product Backlog Item",
    "Epic" : "Epic",
    "Task" : "Task",
    "Feature" : "Feature",
    "Test Case" : "Test Case"
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Prashant shivhare, we need to make sure that both of the projects follow the same Process in the Azure DevOps organization. You can also refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621967/how-do-i-move-work-items-from-one-organization-to-another) to migrate work items to another organization, I have tried it and it works, please try it and then kindly share the result here.

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT , My source is CMMI and the target is scrum. Now I have successfully migrated work-items Like Bug, Task, Epic, Feature, Requirement, Test Case, etc. but I am not able to migrate Related works like Parent and child relationship.Could you help me?

Comment: Hi @Prashant shivhare, Sorry to reply you so late. I have added answer and shared a workaround, please try it and then kindly share the result here. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Prashant shivhare, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT Firstly Thank you so much for the reply. I have successfully migrated work-items from CMMI to SCRUM with links. I got the idea from your post on how to do that all the things.

Answer (score 0):

Create work item query->query type is **Tree of work items**->Select all work items in the query result and select the option move to team project->select target project team->click the query tab Results->Click the button Save items to save all work items.

[image]